# lmdb error: lmdb_lockerror mdb_txn_begin Resource temporarily unavaliable

Tags: database, lmdb

My research is about deep learning, I made a lmdb to accelarate io speed on our company NFS server.

When I lauanch >2 tasks, the first task will run correctly, however the later task I lauanched will cause the error:

> lmdb_lockerror mdb_txn_begin  Resource temporarily unavaliable.

the error position is at

> lmdb.open(my_lmdb_path)

Our server has multiple gpu, and my pre-task only cost 1 gpu, ideally I hope I can run 4 task at the same time.

Would you please help figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use LMDB on remote filesystems like NFS, as described in the docs:

> Do not use LMDB databases on remote filesystems, even between processes on the same host. This breaks flock() on some OSes, possibly memory map sync, and certainly sync between programs on different hosts.

http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/